# Steam crashes on update (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, updates, games, steam

I just installed steam, when I open it, it says that it is downloading update. Right when if finishes, it crashes, when I open it back up, it downloads the update again and so it goes. Please help me do steam. Here is how the terminal looks like when I open steam.

````
[2021-05-02 13:45:09] Startup - updater built Apr  9 2019 22:48:20
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Verifying installation...
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/sandro/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Verification complete
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Downloading Update...
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Checking for available update...
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.1ca83d76835b4613170f5cead778b176b11f2b0c missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.33245b7d523f68418283e93b0572508fa127ee8f missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.7673e4cd32b6752bc621d8bc1a7118a9af19b64a_12077027 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.89b80bcfdd11b2b99257ddbbdc374e2df54e2738 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.ffef2b2fc386819a842ea79484b966a937c2ca7e_1209792 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.3068f03284bffd434b35a595a4075a61908f0f90_32858345 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.d39e0152cbcf41591015157f8e1921e9b2815023_2351629 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file friendsui_all.zip.vz.25ab4d6da88cdfee05a0ec13d23542be8a590c50_2460503 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file steamui_websrc_all.zip.vz.cdb8730f79b432e347ffbabe8f90d7fb831b04db_2780043 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.4a1fa88d21b005b67a41a9a0fc6044ae1fa46791_2225211 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file resources_music_all.zip.vz.7a62e15083d4a65668f0d1fa58ad8c1b99fb5ace_3708050 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file resources_hidpi_all.zip.vz.a6ec169f53f3e3efaebc05c1a68c1aeb567c5847_57918 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.1007fd2145b770678230d2011e2c501f9284b891_1308684 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file strings_en_all.zip.28f4aa5e0d97c8ea457f75b0982d514710946fd4 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.9ff1ff4eeda6002a8fc83d2ff4f09a9817089b4c_1946789 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file public_all.zip.vz.038874e230f3088aff83fa11ddac3b79b59decec_4856931 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.99454288ed7a8cfc6e1cbb43ae69d7768efe815d_24632055 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.ee60302dc07ecafed9131714c8c455168d2bdc38_9044643 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.292c2783860f7e9656990f335991d6e7d996269e_15683221 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.9bd679476290a0b03ff0e532931a5efa1e40436d_2540224 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.vz.46a455a13d6d2ee05e0641f2a58ac2ddf74a792a_14613624 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.ca0433fe0b3dbb89f8b55f2ec6ad507405db6322_55089920 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4fd048667c97ef6eb976f4c42ce5c18f8695ac9e_295483 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.e17be356b525d3defd282305d96d3f27c510c595_1452875 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.69fb9cffcff70f294e99d0bd0d4d1d71d5764926_2007208 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.7ab237873ea5bad5f7c802b9fc5acbc0881b014e missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.09e41a1592f49592287c3d3442a48bd009fe38cd missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Package file runtime_part2_ubuntu12.zip.7dfb5235e78b4ad137d47b314c044464228ac441 missing or incorrect size
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_misc_all.zip.1ca83d76835b4613170f5cead778b176b11f2b0c
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.33245b7d523f68418283e93b0572508fa127ee8f
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.7673e4cd32b6752bc621d8bc1a7118a9af19b64a_12077027
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.89b80bcfdd11b2b99257ddbbdc374e2df54e2738
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.ffef2b2fc386819a842ea79484b966a937c2ca7e_1209792
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.3068f03284bffd434b35a595a4075a61908f0f90_32858345
[2021-05-02 13:45:10] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/tenfoot_all.zip.vz.d39e0152cbcf41591015157f8e1921e9b2815023_2351629
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/friendsui_all.zip.vz.25ab4d6da88cdfee05a0ec13d23542be8a590c50_2460503
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/steamui_websrc_all.zip.vz.cdb8730f79b432e347ffbabe8f90d7fb831b04db_2780043
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/resources_misc_all.zip.vz.4a1fa88d21b005b67a41a9a0fc6044ae1fa46791_2225211
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/resources_music_all.zip.vz.7a62e15083d4a65668f0d1fa58ad8c1b99fb5ace_3708050
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/resources_hidpi_all.zip.vz.a6ec169f53f3e3efaebc05c1a68c1aeb567c5847_57918
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/resources_all.zip.vz.1007fd2145b770678230d2011e2c501f9284b891_1308684
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/strings_en_all.zip.28f4aa5e0d97c8ea457f75b0982d514710946fd4
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/strings_all.zip.vz.9ff1ff4eeda6002a8fc83d2ff4f09a9817089b4c_1946789
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/public_all.zip.vz.038874e230f3088aff83fa11ddac3b79b59decec_4856931
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.99454288ed7a8cfc6e1cbb43ae69d7768efe815d_24632055
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.ee60302dc07ecafed9131714c8c455168d2bdc38_9044643
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.292c2783860f7e9656990f335991d6e7d996269e_15683221
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.9bd679476290a0b03ff0e532931a5efa1e40436d_2540224
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.vz.46a455a13d6d2ee05e0641f2a58ac2ddf74a792a_14613624
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.ca0433fe0b3dbb89f8b55f2ec6ad507405db6322_55089920
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4fd048667c97ef6eb976f4c42ce5c18f8695ac9e_295483
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.e17be356b525d3defd282305d96d3f27c510c595_1452875
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.69fb9cffcff70f294e99d0bd0d4d1d71d5764926_2007208
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.7ab237873ea5bad5f7c802b9fc5acbc0881b014e
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.09e41a1592f49592287c3d3442a48bd009fe38cd
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Add pending download: cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/runtime_part2_ubuntu12.zip.7dfb5235e78b4ad137d47b314c044464228ac441
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Downloading update (1,953 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:11] Downloading update (2,597 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:12] Downloading update (3,082 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:12] Downloading update (3,705 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:12] Downloading update (4,453 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:12] Downloading update (5,315 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:13] Downloading update (6,127 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:13] Downloading update (7,070 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:13] Downloading update (8,186 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:13] Downloading update (9,191 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:14] Downloading update (10,147 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:14] Downloading update (11,280 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:14] Downloading update (12,223 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:14] Downloading update (13,369 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:15] Downloading update (14,392 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:15] Downloading update (15,325 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:15] Downloading update (16,417 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:15] Downloading update (17,758 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:16] Downloading update (18,824 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:16] Downloading update (19,523 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:16] Downloading update (20,186 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:16] Downloading update (20,777 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:17] Downloading update (21,484 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:17] Downloading update (21,848 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:17] Downloading update (22,329 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:17] Downloading update (22,644 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:18] Downloading update (23,025 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:18] Downloading update (23,605 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:18] Downloading update (23,961 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:18] Downloading update (24,258 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:19] Downloading update (24,532 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:19] Downloading update (24,829 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:19] Downloading update (25,190 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:19] Downloading update (25,534 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:20] Downloading update (25,542 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:20] Downloading update (25,892 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:20] Downloading update (26,313 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:20] Downloading update (26,641 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:21] Downloading update (26,712 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:21] Downloading update (26,994 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:21] Downloading update (27,231 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:21] Downloading update (27,493 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:22] Downloading update (27,776 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:22] Downloading update (28,033 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:22] Downloading update (28,316 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:22] Downloading update (28,391 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:23] Downloading update (28,876 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:23] Downloading update (29,237 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:23] Downloading update (29,628 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:23] Downloading update (30,037 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:24] Downloading update (30,507 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:24] Downloading update (30,939 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:24] Downloading update (31,306 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:24] Downloading update (31,830 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:25] Downloading update (32,382 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:25] Downloading update (33,032 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:25] Downloading update (33,827 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:25] Downloading update (34,658 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:26] Downloading update (34,915 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:26] Downloading update (35,589 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:26] Downloading update (36,546 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:27] Downloading update (37,476 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:27] Downloading update (39,011 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:27] Downloading update (39,697 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:27] Downloading update (40,403 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:28] Downloading update (41,027 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:28] Downloading update (41,994 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:28] Downloading update (42,271 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:28] Downloading update (43,114 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:29] Downloading update (43,735 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:29] Downloading update (44,591 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:29] Downloading update (45,479 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:29] Downloading update (46,389 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:30] Downloading update (47,145 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:30] Downloading update (48,055 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:30] Downloading update (48,755 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:30] Downloading update (49,484 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:31] Downloading update (50,341 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:31] Downloading update (51,147 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:31] Downloading update (52,000 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:31] Downloading update (52,841 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:32] Downloading update (53,873 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:32] Downloading update (54,884 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:32] Downloading update (55,765 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:32] Downloading update (56,926 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:33] Downloading update (57,716 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:33] Downloading update (58,604 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:33] Downloading update (59,681 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:33] Downloading update (60,682 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:34] Downloading update (62,125 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:34] Downloading update (63,035 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:34] Downloading update (63,980 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:34] Downloading update (64,918 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:35] Downloading update (65,873 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:35] Downloading update (66,853 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:35] Downloading update (67,446 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:35] Downloading update (68,422 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:36] Downloading update (69,576 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:36] Downloading update (70,640 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:36] Downloading update (71,474 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:36] Downloading update (72,250 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:37] Downloading update (73,290 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:37] Downloading update (74,290 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:37] Downloading update (75,247 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:37] Downloading update (76,283 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:38] Downloading update (77,529 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:38] Downloading update (78,442 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:38] Downloading update (79,168 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:38] Downloading update (80,089 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:39] Downloading update (80,977 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:39] Downloading update (82,131 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:39] Downloading update (82,969 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:39] Downloading update (83,872 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:40] Downloading update (84,864 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:40] Downloading update (85,853 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:40] Downloading update (86,754 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:41] Downloading update (87,727 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:41] Downloading update (88,626 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:41] Downloading update (89,549 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:41] Downloading update (90,431 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:42] Downloading update (91,380 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:42] Downloading update (92,373 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:42] Downloading update (93,466 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:42] Downloading update (94,485 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:43] Downloading update (95,822 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:43] Downloading update (96,971 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:43] Downloading update (98,115 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:43] Downloading update (99,346 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:44] Downloading update (100,657 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:44] Downloading update (102,189 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:44] Downloading update (103,669 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:44] Downloading update (104,941 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:45] Downloading update (106,378 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:45] Downloading update (107,433 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:45] Downloading update (108,296 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:45] Downloading update (109,250 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:46] Downloading update (110,321 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:46] Downloading update (111,320 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:46] Downloading update (112,351 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:46] Downloading update (113,438 of 288,058 KB)...
[2021-05-02 13:45:47] Downloading update (114,478 of 288,058 KB)...
Terminated```
````

Comment: Try rebooting your machine. Sometimes when there is an NVidia driver update outside of Steam (don't know if it's the same with AMD cards), Steam will refuse to start up. A reboot will fix that.

Comment: I tried rebooting many times, also I have AMD, it still does not work.